# How to set specific Date to the DateTimePicker in Pascal(Lazarus) ? I need set a 01.01.1991 for example? Can't find info about it

Tags: date, datetimepicker, freepascal, lazarus

Certain date into DateTimePicker (Pascal)

How to add a certain and specific date into DateTimePicker in the Pascal/Lazarus ?

Comment: Lazarus *or* Delphi?

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand: TItle says Lazarus.

Answer (score 1):

Delphi's [`TDateTimePicker`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.ComCtrls.TDateTimePicker) and FPC's [`TDateTimePicker`](https://wiki.freepascal.org/TDateTimePicker) both have [`Date`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.ComCtrls.TCommonCalendar.Date) and [`DateTime`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.ComCtrls.TCommonCalendar.DateTime) properties, which you can set to a specific date, eg:

```pascal
DateTimePicker1.Date := EncodeDate(1991, 1, 1);
```

Comment: Exactly the same code works also in FPC.